# Windows 10 stops with CRITICAL_PROCESS_DIED

Tags: windows-10, boot, bsod, logging

I have a Dell Latitude laptop shipped with Windows 10, which ran without problems until I had the idea to run an older Windows install from an external SSD in USB. It booted and worked (still works), but after this, the original OS on the built-in SSD failed to boot. According to the boot log, it stops early after loading the kernel, it never even starts loading the device drivers. All I have in ntbtlog is this few lines:

```
Ŕ 1  1 2023 16:16:10.500
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\kd.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\system32\mcupdate_GenuineIntel.dll
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\CLFS.SYS
BOOTLOG_LOADED \SystemRoot\System32\drivers\tm.sys
```

I researched on resolving this issue, and the primary tool recommended in this case seemed to be `sfc /scannow`, which seems to lock up at the very beginning, without any output, but in the task manager, it can be seen that it is using the disk intensely, in the range of 10 MB/s, but never finishes, I let it run for 8 hours, and nothing changed.
Any help would be much appreciated as I completely depend on this installation during my work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your post, but I assume that the
older Windows version that you booted externally was previous to
Windows 10.

The problem might arise because each major new version of Windows modifies
the NTFS format. Newer Windows versions support older NTFS versions,
but not vice-versa, so the older Windows might have modified the
internal disk destructively.

If there is any data on the disk that needs saving, I suggest to either
[boot to the Command Prompt](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-start-command-prompt-when-windows-doesnt-boot/)
or use a Linux Live USB.

Then I suggest to run the
[latest Windows 10 boot media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)
and try to do
[Startup Repair](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html).

If this doesn't help, you will need to reinstall Windows.
If you're lucky, the installation will detect the existing version
and just upgrade it. Otherwise, this will be a clean install.
You may also need to download drivers from the Dell website.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The older version that I booted was also Windows 10. I will give the startup repair from the installer, but I suspect that it uses the same tool internally (sfc). It would be important to keep this installation running, I cannot reinstall the software I need on a clean install.